# How to Get Min and Max DateTime from MongoDB using c# queries?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I wrote query for Sorting and MAX and MIN Records of DateTime using MongoDB c# queries.
i wrote as

```
var server = MongoServer.Create(this.connectionString);
var db = server.GetDatabase(DATABASE);
var tblRskAlerts = db.GetCollection(RISKALERT_TBL);
var query = Query.And(Query.EQ("Entry", null));
var sort = tblRskAlerts.Find(query).SetSortOrder(SortBy.Ascending("Entry"));
var sort =SortBy.Ascending("Entry");
var fromDt = sort.Max(x => x["Entry"].ToJson());
var toDt = sort.Min(x => x["Entry"].ToJson());
txtToCal.Text = ((DateTime)toDt).ToLocalTime();
```

Now i want to show fromDt,toDt into Textboxes.
But I got error as Can not convert String into DateTime.

Comment: Mb you looking for [DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) method? You question no very clear...

Answer (score 7):

I'm guessing that your question can be rephrased as follows:

1. I have a collection where some documents have an Entry field and some don't
2. I want to find the smallest and largest values present in the collection for those documents that actually have a value for the Entry field.

It is often best to figure things out in the MongoDB shell first and then translate to C# after you're done experimenting.

The following shell statements create some sample data:

```
> db.test.remove()
> db.test.insert({})
> db.test.insert({Entry:ISODate("2011-12-01")})
> db.test.insert({Entry:ISODate("2011-12-02")})
> db.test.insert({Entry:ISODate("2011-12-03")})
```

This is what the documents just inserted look like:

```
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4efa1208a981bdd43ddcacd0") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4efa1215a981bdd43ddcacd1"), "Entry" : ISODate("2011-12-01T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4efa1218a981bdd43ddcacd2"), "Entry" : ISODate("2011-12-02T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4efa121ba981bdd43ddcacd3"), "Entry" : ISODate("2011-12-03T00:00:00Z") }
```

Notice that one of them doesn't have an Entry field. We can exclude it from the results using an $exists query:

```
> db.test.find({Entry:{$exists:true}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4efa1215a981bdd43ddcacd1"), "Entry" : ISODate("2011-12-01T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4efa1218a981bdd43ddcacd2"), "Entry" : ISODate("2011-12-02T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4efa121ba981bdd43ddcacd3"), "Entry" : ISODate("2011-12-03T00:00:00Z") }
```

Now to find the documents containing the smallest and largest values we can sort twice, once ascending and once descending, and limit the result to one document:

```
> db.test.find({Entry:{$exists:true}}).sort({Entry:1}).limit(1)
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4efa1215a981bdd43ddcacd1"), "Entry" : ISODate("2011-12-01T00:00:00Z") }
> db.test.find({Entry:{$exists:true}}).sort({Entry:-1}).limit(1)
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4efa121ba981bdd43ddcacd3"), "Entry" : ISODate("2011-12-03T00:00:00Z") }
```

Then it's just a matter of extracting the Entry value from the document.

Here's what it looks like in C# code:

```
var server = MongoServer.Create("mongodb://localhost/?safe=true");
var database = server["test"];
var collection = database["test"];
collection.Drop();

collection.Insert(new BsonDocument());
collection.Insert(new BsonDocument("Entry", new DateTime(2011, 12, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)));
collection.Insert(new BsonDocument("Entry", new DateTime(2011, 12, 2, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)));
collection.Insert(new BsonDocument("Entry", new DateTime(2011, 12, 3, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)));

var query = Query.Exists("Entry", true);
var sortAscending = SortBy.Ascending("Entry");
var sortDescending = SortBy.Descending("Entry");

foreach (var document in collection.Find(query).SetSortOrder(sortAscending))
{
    Console.WriteLine(document.ToJson());
}
Console.WriteLine();

var minDocument = collection.Find(query).SetSortOrder(sortAscending).SetLimit(1).First();
var maxDocument = collection.Find(query).SetSortOrder(sortDescending).SetLimit(1).First();

var minDateTime = minDocument["Entry"].AsDateTime;
var maxDateTime = maxDocument["Entry"].AsDateTime;

Console.WriteLine("Min Entry = {0}", minDateTime.ToString("o"));
Console.WriteLine("Max Entry = {0}", maxDateTime.ToString("o"));
```

The full test program is at: http://www.pastie.org/3080660

Comment: I should add that in order for this to be efficient with large collections you will want to create an index on Entry.